# Remove key: value pair from nested objects

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I have this object:

```
const myObject = {
  myNestedObject1: {
    key1: "key1",
    key2: "key2",
    key3: "key3"
  },
  myNestedObject2: {
    key1: "key1",
    key2: "key2",
    key3: "key3"
  },
  myNestedObject3: {
    key1: "key1",
    key2: "key2",
    key3: "key3"
  }
}
```

I want to get a new similar object, but without the key-value pair `key2: "key2"`, and without mutating the original one.

```
const myObject = {
  myNestedObject1: {
    key1: "key1",
    key3: "key3"
  },
  myNestedObject2: {
    key1: "key1",
    key3: "key3"
  },
  myNestedObject3: {
    key1: "key1",
    key3: "key3"
  }
}
```

Is there any short and easy way to do it? Lodash maybe?

Thanks!

---

As requested, this is what I'm trying:

```
const myObject = {
  myNestedObject1: {
    key1: "key1",
    key2: "key2",
    key3: "key3",
  },
  myNestedObject2: {
    key1: "key1",
    key2: "key2",
    key3: "key3",
  },
  myNestedObject3: {
    key1: "key1",
    key2: "key2",
    key3: "key3",
  },
};

 result = _.transform(
  Object.assign({}, myObject),
  (acc, value, key) => {
    delete value["key2"]

    acc[key] = value;
  },
  {}
);
```

Which produces the desired object, but mutates the original one.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? please post the code,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const myObject = {myNestedObject1: {key1: "key1",key2: "key2",key3: "key3"}, myNestedObject2: {key1: "key1",key2: "key2",key3: "key3"}, myNestedObject3: {key1: "key1",key2: "key2",key3: "key3"}};

const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(myObject).map(([key, value]) => {
   const {key2, ...rest} = value; // Get all the keys except key2 at ...rest
   return [key, rest];
}));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

#### Update

Here I propose an alternative approach using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const myObject = {myNestedObject1: {key1: "key1",key2: "key2",key3: "key3"}, myNestedObject2: {key1: "key1",key2: "key2",key3: "key3"}, myNestedObject3: {key1: "key1",key2: "key2",key3: "key3"}};

const res = Object.entries(myObject).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
 const {key2, ...rest} = value;
 return {...acc, [key]: rest}
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

Comment: This is interesting, but what if your nested objects have many entries? In that case would be better to remove the undesired entry rather than adding the desired ones…

Comment: Thank you for your response @EmilleC. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, spread operator, makes sense… don't get exactly how fromEntries works here, good moment to read about it. Thanks!

Comment: There is a drawback with this solution: `fromEntries` is not widely supported, so al alternative would be awesome

Comment: Hey @EmilleC. you should use any JavaScript compiler/converter like ```Babel``` for browser supports and embrace the new ES features.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop through the object and delete the object property:

```js
const myObject = {
  myNestedObject1: {
    key1: "key1",
    key2: "key2",
    key3: "key3",
  },
  myNestedObject2: {
    key1: "key1",
    key2: "key2",
    key3: "key3",
  },
  myNestedObject3: {
    key1: "key1",
    key2: "key2",
    key3: "key3",
  },
};
const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject)); //make a shallow copy of the object
for(let o in result){
  delete result[o]['key2'];
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `on side note:-` the question says `Which produces the desired object, but mutates the original one.` so as your answer as well, i think op needs an immutable way to handle this

Comment: Sorry, this was added in my solution as a drawback: I want to avoid mutation.